# Add a conditional clause to Delete a table's rows matching a list's items

Tags: c#, sql, system.data.sqlite

I have a list of items (containing integer ids). I need to delete all row of a table X whose id column's data match with these list items.
I am using sqlite and here is how I have tried

```
List<int> lstItem=new List<int>();
//add data to lstItem
//....
SqlComm.CommandText="delete from X where id in @lstItem";
```

Comment: I think you have to do that in a loop for each list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the items:

```
var sbSql = new System.Text.StringBuilder(500);

sbSql.Append("delete from X where id in (");

if (lstItem.Count != 0) {
  foreach (int value in lstItem)
  {
     if (sbSql.Length != 0) 
     {
        sbSql.Append(",");
     }
     sbSql.Append(value);
  }

} else {
   sbSql.Append(-1);
}

sbSql.Append(")");

SqlComm.CommandText = sbSql.ToString();
```